# "@media only screen and" is not removed based on the input

Tags: css, angularjs, html, less

I am implementing a HTML application based on responsive design.
I am using "@media only screen" for responsive styling.

I am using the below Css Code for mobile orientation(Landscape/Portrait):

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 465px), screen and (max-width: 465px)
.align {
    width: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 736px), screen and (max-width: 736px)
.align {
    width: 25%;
}
```

The first one is for vertical and second one is for landscape styles.
The issue is when I changing the browser orientation form Portrait to landscape, the Portrait style is not removed in css both styles are in enabled state but if I reduce the browser size the vertical style is removed and the landscape style is taking the responsibility.
So How do I remove the unwanted style from my page without changing the browser window size.

Comment: Don't use `device-width` *unless you absolutely know **why** you are using it*. Use `width` instead only. For orientation, use just that! `(orientation: landscape)` respectively `(orientation: portrait)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide some additional condition with orientation

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Comment: Again, for common media queries you don't want to work with `device-width`, but `width`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also define the css without orientation I think, by defining the media width is enough for styling

```
@media (max-width: 465px){

//Do your styling here

}

@media (max-width: 1024px){

//Do your styling here

}
```

This will help u style the css not only for mobile portrait and lanscape but also for device that are in screen size.